# whats the problem? (@react-navigation/native-stack)

Tags: react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZkId.png)

```
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNCSafeAreaProvider" was not found in the UIManager.

This error is located at:
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by NativeStackView)
    in NativeStackView (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in NativeStackNavigator (created by App)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in ThemeProvider
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by App)
    in App
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in TechCareer(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
```

I added the  react-navigation and then it started giving me trouble. I've checked a lot of places, but I haven't found a solution to the problem. I could use some help

```
NavigationContainer not working
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you either deleted or forgot to install `react-native-safe-area-context`. To be safe, you might as well install `react-native-screens` as well.

For react-native project

```
npm install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context && cd ios && npx pod install && cd ..
```

For expo

```
npx expo install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context
```

More info on [setup](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/)